# Is it possible to send raw json with IRestClient

Tags: servicestack

I love the simplicity of using servicestack's IRestClient to test my api, but I need to replicate a test scenario when someone sends an incomplete object. For instance if my dto looks like this:

```
public class Todo
    {
        public long? Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int? Order { get; set; }
        public bool? Done { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to do a PUT with partial json like this:

```
{"Id": 99999, "Order":1}
```

How do I send just the above with the json client. If I use the typed version the client sends the entire object with defaults.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be easier to use ServiceStack's [Http Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils#posting-data) (link is to POST but applies to PUT) to PUT the data.

```
"http://localhost/todo"
    .PutJsonToUrl(@"{""Id"":9999,""Order"":1}");
```

Also, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to test. But, if you're testing your Service the request (your json string) will be deserialized (pretty sure using ServiceStack.Text) into the Todo class so it will get the object with defaults for missing fields. See the test below.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestJson()
    {
        var json = @"{""Id"": 99999, ""Order"":1}";

        var todo = new ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer<Todo>().DeserializeFromString(json);

        Assert.IsNull(todo.Done);
        Assert.IsNull(todo.Content);
    }
```